# Shopping Cart Price Rules: Fixed amount % Percentage MIX

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

Magento 1.9.1

I want to give my clients 28$ discount on a list of particular items. My problem, is that some of the item's price is below 28. So with my "fixed price" rule i end up giving customers free money.

Question: Is it possible to have a mix of % and fixed value? So the rule will be "give 100% discount on the item, but this 100% should not exceed 28$?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with one rule but with 2 it is. Make one rule with a condition where the item or cart is less then $28, here you set a percentage. The second rule has a minimal item/cart amount of over $28 where you set the amount to a fixed value.